# How can I clone maps in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So far I was able to create clones of map_0, just by pressing shift while taking the map from the crafting table.

But is there any (ingame) way to create a clone of, say, map_1? If not is there a cheat or a server command to clone maps other than map_0?

Comment: That's a glitch.

Comment: @Duck A mighty useful glitch! *goes to clone some maps*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spawn a map item. Then go into the server's world folder->data, and delete the new maps' files. (like if you want to clone map_3 as map_0, delete map_3) then, copy and paste map_0 (or whatever map you're cloning, and rename it to the new map (example, map_3) Notch may add a cloning feature in the future, though!

Comment: however this copies the map but doesn't create two markers like the first one

Answer (score 4):

Using in-game server commands does work.

```
/give [playerId] [itemId]:[mapId] [amount]
```

E.g. `/give player1 358:2 1` clones map_2 for player1's use.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on a vanilla server - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24268/how-to-clone-maps-in-minecraft-smp-1-6-6#question

Comment: @badp what mods/packages/whatever elses do i need to install for this to work then?

Comment: @chands you should ask that as a new question, e.g. "how to give items with damage value other than zero in smp". then I'd answer something like "you can use [bukkit](http://bukkit.org) with the [CommandBook plugin](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/gen-tp-admn-commandbook-1-5-2-essential-and-useful-commands-item-etc-818.6525/)"

Comment: @Tobias: If you would sir(or madam...?): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24524/8736

Answer (score 3):

On a vanilla server, you can do /give (player) 358 1 (map-id)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor/), you can put the map into a chest and copy the chest. This seems a bit easier than the renaming thing.

Answer (score 1):

earlier the suggestion of placing "/give player1 358:2 1" in the cheats bar was given. I tried it but for me it didn't work. But I used that as the basis for another code which will work if the above doesn't:

/give [player1] 358 1 1

the "358" is the ID of the map.
the first "1" is how many copies you want.
the second "1" is which map value. Automatically, it's 0. So if you had only "358 1" you'd get a copy of map_0. But the 1 specifies which map_# you want.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can now clone maps much more easily.

> A mix of empty maps and empty locator maps may be used. Whether the cloned maps show position markers is dependent only on the input map.
>
> A cartography table can also be used to clone a map.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Cloning