# How to clone maps in Minecraft SMP (1.6.6)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I clone maps in SMP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23866/how-can-i-clone-maps-in-smp)

I'm running a vanilla Minecraft server updated to 1.6.6.  We're trying to make clones of maps other than map_0, however the command **/give player 358:1 1** does not work.  Instead it says "There is no item with id 358:1"

Everyone says that command works, and apparently we're the only ones having issues.  To be clear, **/give player 358:1 1** *does not work*, and we're wondering why not...?