# How do I give items like colored wool, different woods, and maps in smp?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know items such as these have data values and damage values associated with them, but I don't know how to set the damage value while `/give`ing these items to players.

I have seen the `/give player data_value:damage_amount quantity` notation used before but that doesn't work on a vanilla server. What mods/plugins do I need for this to work?

Comment: Hmm, I thought the command would work on a Vanilla server. Bukkit Servers have this integrated.

Comment: @Kevin plain bukkit server or do i need to add a specific mod to bukkit?

Comment: I think CraftBukkit itself supplies the commands (as in, a plain Bukkit server). However, it *might* be part of the Essentials plugin.

Comment: The command itself does work for vanilla servers (with the possible exception of damage_amount).  The problem is different colored wools, wood types, and maps have additional information.  For example the /give command will only spawn white wool on a vanilla server.

Comment: @Kevin the last time I tried it without plugins it didn't work, I now use [CommandBook](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/gen-tp-admn-commandbook-1-5-2-essential-and-useful-commands-item-etc-818.6525/)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yup, those different wool colours, wood types, etc. are stored in the `damage_amount` value of the block (weird, I know).

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I know it works with the exception of damage_amount. that's the point of the question: How do I make `/give` work with damage amounts.

Comment: @chands - Sorry I should have specified.  That comment was intended to clarify that the /give command does work on vanilla servers and that you wanted an alternate version to provide different colors of wool, etc.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - No harm done, you made a good point! It will definitely be helpful to others who see this question.

Comment: is there an answer for vanilla yet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `damage_amount` part of the `/give player data_value:damage_amount quantity` notation only works when you install the [Essentials](http://ess.earth2me.com/index.php/Essentials_News) plugin for [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/).

For example:

- `/give player_name 35:1 quantity` gives you orange wool
- `/give player_name 35:2 quantity` gives you magenta wool
- `/give player_name 44:3 quantity` gives you cobblestone slabs
- `/give player_name 358:1 quantity` gives you `map_1`

Note that this syntax also works for the `/i` command, except it does not require the `player_name` variable (giving yourself).

Answer (score 13):

For a vanilla server you have to use

`/give [playername] [data-value] [amount] [damage-value]`

Comment: it seems to have changed, you have to use item names now like glass or wool

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this:

```
/give [name] [blockid] [amount] [damagevalue]
```

for example, for dark planks do

```
/give [name] 5 [amount] 1
```

Comment: Hi Tobuscusfan, and welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, your answer doesn't provide any new information that hasn't been stated in other answers.  When answering, especially questions that already have a lot of answers, please provide new information instead of restating others' answers.

Answer (score 2):

Any OP in a vanilla server can give blocks through the syntax "/give player block_id quantity" such as "/give chands 20 64" to give yourself 64 glass. You can use the Bukkit server which allows plugins to be easily installed. I believe the command I'm thinking of is in Bukkit Essentials which allows the following.

- "/i dirt" - Gives yourself 64 dirt
- "/i ch dirt" - It would give the first player with that contains 'ch' a stack of 64 dirt.

EDIT: I forgot to mention the official server does not allow damage values which is how the game treats wool, wood, and birches as unique blocks.

There is also a plugin called 'World Edit'. It's a very powerful tool. You select two x/y coordinates and can do many things. Replace, remove, or set a block type. Stack the selected blocks so you can create a repeating pattern (a wall, bridge, etc) and it'll repeat it in the selected direction x amount of times. All sorts of stuff.

- [Bukkit's Main page](http://bukkit.org/)
- [Bukkit Essentials](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/quite-active-gen-essentials-v2-1-please-change-owner-to-essentialsteam.1262/)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the already mentioned [Essentials](http://ess.earth2me.com/index.php/Essentials_News) plugin for [bukkit](http://bukkit.org/), you can also use the [CommandBook plugin](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/gen-tp-admn-commandbook-1-5-2-essential-and-useful-commands-item-etc-818.6525/). Just compare which has the features you prefer - CommandBook (as well as essentials) supports item names, e.g. you can use `/give chands Wood:2`.

Comment: +1: I love the fact that you can use item names and don't have to fiddle with item id's! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for vanilla it is now:
`/give player itemname amount dv`

at least this is working for me:

`/give player stained_glass 63 3` where 3 is light blue