# What is the spawn code for pine wood in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What spawn code do I need to use to spawn pine wood block in multiplayer? On some website I saw something like 17-1 (17 for the sapling, and 1 for pine since 1 is the type of a sapling).. But when I try spawning 17-1, i get the "There's no item with id 17-1" message. Oh and I tried googleing, but can't find the code anywhere.. Hints? Thank you.

(using up-to-date Minecraft 1.7)

Comment: Tried "17:1"? Colon is what's typically used.

Comment: yes, I tried 17-1, 17:1, 17.1 and 17,1 and none worked.. :S

Comment: please don't change the topic from wood to sapling again.. I want a wooden block, not a sapling. thank you.

Comment: People were changing the title because you said "sapling" in the question. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vanilla support for this has been added.  The syntax is:

```
/give <playername> <data-value> [amount] [damage-value]
```

Note that if you specify a damage value, you *must* specify an amount.

So for this specific case, you would use:

```
/give <your-name> 6 <how-much-you-want> 1
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't spawn things with special data attached in the base game, such as pine saplings or colored wool.

You need a mod, like [bukkit](http://bukkit.org/).

Then, the command would be `/give BlueRaja 6:1 64`

[image: (image of saplings)]

Comment: I installed bukkit, and I still can't get neither 6:1 nor 17:1... that's strange.. I guess?

Comment: @pootzko: you'll need to install essentials for bukkit - see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24524/how-to-give-items-like-colored-wool-different-woods-and-maps-in-smp/24534#24534)

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Ok, I've actually set up a server on my machine and tested this, it appears that with a vanilla Minecraft server the suffices for different types of sapling ***do not work***, so you can only spawn 'plain' saplings.

*(Old Answer)*

> From [the
>  wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saplings)
>  it appears to be 6. Try 6:1.

Comment: nope, I still get the same "There's no item with id x" message..

Comment: @pootzko You need a number, space, dash, space, number, for example /give bob 17 - 2. However this won't work with a quantity as well, it will only give 1

Comment: @Dan - well, I don't really need this any more at all since now one can simply use creative mode.. =)

Answer (score -2):

I've had this problem too but I got it to work.

/give [your name] 17 64 1

The Damage Value is the second part of the ID after the colon :