# Cloned maps in Minecraft SMP without cheating

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can maps be cloned in SMP **without cheating**? (i.e. without editing saves or using /give or similar commands).

Can this be done only at creation time (all the clones are created together), or can they be also cloned later (you already have a map and you clone it)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to run a new/separate map? Should it be completely identical to the old one (cloned), with all the changes you made, items, etc.? Copying the map files suffices.

Or do you only want the _terrain_ to be the same? If so, copying the level seed should do the trick.

Comment: It used to be that you could hold down the shift key while taking a map from the crafting table to create a copy of the very first map created in that world, but only that very first map.

Comment: @ver - I think he means Map Object in the game, rather than the game world.

Comment: Similar to this question?: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23866/how-can-i-clone-maps-in-smp

Comment: @Kurley Yeaaaah, when I started reading your first comment, it dawned on me. :)

Comment: @Kurley: It's similar but all the answers there are cheats, which I explicitly exclude here.

Comment: LOL at the downvote. Some people are just stupid. (including those who think secret voting makes sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 12w34a it is possible to [clone maps](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_%28item%29#Cloning). Recipe putting an "empty map" to the right of the "original map", which will create two copies of the "original map".

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to clone maps at the moment without cheating using the /give or /i command.
It's stated on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_%28Item%29#Multiplayer) that maps can only be cloned by using a command.

Below is a quote from [Notch's Blog](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/4988431144/the-maps), he said that there will be some way to clone maps. He has not yet implemented a way to do so (wthout cheating).

> You will also be able to (somehow) CLONE maps so that two separate map
> items link to the same map data.

So in short, no at the moment you'll have to use the /i or /give command. Until Jeb makes a way to do so.

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100%, but I think you can make the same exact world by using the same exact seed. If you do that anything you createdor destroyed wont copy, but the landforms should.

Comment: I'm 99.98% sure the question is about [maps](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Map) not worlds.